# Is it impossible to use private class field(js) in raspberrypi?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

the code below works well on window, but the error occur when I try to run it on raspberrypi4

```
const { AES } = require('./crypto');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const { load } = require('cheerio');   

class KakaoLink {
    #apiKey;
    #cookies = {};
    #referer = null;
    
    constructor(apiKey, location) {
        this.#apiKey = apiKey;
        this.#kakaoStatic += encodeURIComponent(location);
    }
}

module.exports = KakaoLink;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xznq3.png)

Comment: Are the node versions on both systems the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are running an older version of Node on the Pi. Private instance fields are part of ES2022 for which you need node version 12.4 or above. You can see the support for different versions here: https://node.green/